# Generic Collections of unknown (sub-class) types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a base abstract class (`baseEntity`), derived from an Interface. From this, I have many sub-classes - each actually represents a database table for NHibernate. Some sub-classes contain properties that are other `baseEntity` classes, and some contain properties that are lists of other `baseEntity` classes. For some of these list properties I converted from using `ILIst/List` to `ISet/HashSet`, to stop an NHIbernate exception seen after upgrading from an ancient version

> Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

**My question is not to do with NHIbernate**
:

```
public interface INhEntity;

public abstract class BaseEntity;

public class OrderItems : baseEntity
{
    // properties
}

public class Order : baseEntity
{
    public virtual ISet<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set;}
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
    }
}
```

We use `ISet/HashSet` because this seemed an easy and safe way to get rid of the multi-bag problem (The `HashSet` will quietly stop duplicates)

We also use messaging to send data between sites. Basically, each `baseEntity` is serialized. At the other end, we deserialize, use `PropertyInfo`, Type details etc to reconstruct the `baseEntity` sub-class
Referring to the `Order/OrderItem` classes above, I need to create/access/get access to the `OrderItem` property. This is where the fun arrives:

When I am processing a Set property, I try accessing as per below:

```
private void ProcessSet(object entity, ListItem listItem, PropertyInfo property)
{
    //entity is an instance of the Order entity
    //listitem contains info I will use to update the order item
    //property is the OrderItems property. It has a vale of:
    //ISet`1[Full.NameSpace.OrderItem] OrderItem}

    var setInstance = GetOrCreateSetInstance(entity, property);
    ...processing
    setInstance.Add(AnOrderItemInstance); //NHibernate knows to link the 2 database tables (OrderItems class does not need/have a FK)
}

private static ISet<baseEntity> GetOrCreateSetInstance(object entity, PropertyInfo prop)
{
    var listInstance = prop.GetValue(entity, null); // This looks just what I want
    var result = (ISet<baseEntity>)listINstance //cannot cast type OrderItem to baseEntity
    return result
}
```

I have similar code to deal with lists. Because I can return a non-generic Ilist, this works a treat. Prior to upgrading NHibernate, I was using the Iesi Isets, so my `GetOrCreateINstance` had this signature:

```
private static Iesi.Collection.ISet GetOrCreateSetInstance(object entity, PropertyInfo prop)
```

Is there anyway I can have a method to return the various subclass instances. Note I have tried returning `HashSet<baseEntity>`, `Iset/HashSet<INhEntity>`

I have tried Casting in various methods, but usually end up with '.. is a variable but is used like a type', 
I actually don't think it's possible, but any feedback most welcome

Comment: Hi @Shane, are you looking for something like?
`var result = new HashSet<baseEntity>(listINstance.OfType<baseEntity>());`
I hope I got you right.

Comment: Hi Denys. In this case, I am after a HashSet<OrderItem>.

Comment: Are entitles in `listINstance` or type `OrderItem`? If so then just replace like this:
`var result = new HashSet<OrderItem>(listINstance.OfType<OrderItem>());`

Comment: Hi @Denys. There are 8 `baseEntity` sub-classes with 32 properties that are lists of other `baseEntity` classes. At compile time I do not know what `Type` they are. The line `var listInstance = prop.GetValue(entity, null);` returns the correct `HashSet`, regardless of which of the 32 properties it is passed. Referring to your example, I have tried something along the lines of
`Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
var result = listInstance as ISet<propType>;`
that gives 'propType' is a variable but is used like a type